# Accessing SOAP service in Java

Tags: java, soap

I need to access a soap service and I have the wsdl url too. How would I go about doing this in java? Are there any good tutorials to achieve this?

Also I have an xml file generated in android to call a soap service but it isnt working. Is there any place I can paste this xml to check if the xml is correctly calling the webservice (I am using wireshark to record the xml being sent and it appears fine).

Comment: You will have to use any webservice libraries like Apache axis or cxf. Both of which provides client code generation from wsdl.

Comment: are you writing on notepad? no ide ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first part of your question, you could use SoapUI ( http://www.soapui.org/ ) to load the WSDL and generate Java Client code for it ( http://nitinaggarwal.wordpress.com/2010/11/12/generating-client-java-code-for-wsdl-using-soap-ui-axis2-wsdl2java/ ). I used this way once but maybe there are better ways to do it.

Comment: How do i run the axis2 genearted java file.

Comment: I have done it using apache-cxf-2.3.2 ( http://cxf.apache.org/ ). I put the generated java package in Eclipse and checked the java files. The basic java files in my case were two: one by the name of the wsdl and another ending with **'_Service.java'**. Among the generated java classes there must also be one ending with **'_Client.java'**. This contains example code for calling all methods of the wsdl using the generated classes. You can export this package as a jar, import it to your main project and then simply call the ws as shown in the example code.

Comment: You may also find this link helpful ( http://www.javadb.com/using-a-message-handler-to-alter-the-soap-header-in-a-web-service-client ) in case you want to add information in the soap header, like authentication, before calling the ws

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to generate a client webservice stub in netbeans. Simply create a new project and then add new web service client. Supply the WSDL and your done. Netbeans also has a great web service tutorial.

Very useful link: http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/web.html

I would suggest staying away from axis web service clients. My experience with axis is not great. wsimport used by netbeans is great so far. Uses JAX-WS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wsimport` (part of JDK 6)

See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html)

Answer (score 0):

[CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) is both powerful and easy-to-use tool for Webservice Client Generation.

[Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis/) does also ws client generation, but I personally had problems with it.